# Bully Scholarship Edition: Unable to get the Nutcracker outfit

Tags: bully

Playing in the Xbox Version of the game, I have completed the mission "Nutcrackin" However, I did not recieve the Nutcracker outfit.

This counts on game completion and is also needed to unlock the 'Elvis Presley' outfit which also counts on game completion.

How do I get the Nutcracker outfit?